# Is there a prebuilt armel version of quantal-preinstalled-phablet-*.zip for ubuntu touch?

Tags: ubuntu-touch

Is there a prebuilt armel version of quantal-preinstalled-phablet-*.zip?
With the armel version, I could port ubuntu touch to some older machines which use armv6.

Answer (score 1):

The only prebuild version (armhf) can be found here:

http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-touch-preview/daily-preinstalled/current/

EDIT:

Info from the mailing list (quotation from ogra, arm developer):

> you mean armel ... no, that was completely dropped from ubuntu a little over a year ago. to make anything support ARMv6 you would have to re-build the whole ubuntu archive for that (obsolete) architecture ...
>   this is very unlikely to happen (like we wont support true i386 or i486 systems on intel anymore)